# How come non-static methods can be called without an object inside the class?

Tags: c++, oop, methods, static-methods

Wherever I search, I find that to use a method without an object, **THE ONLY WAY IS TO MAKE IT STATIC**. However,
in the following piece of code I show two examples of non static methods being called without an object `FindIngredient` and `NumPizzas()`((*) and (**)). It compiles and not even warnings are given. As you can see I am not using static anywhere

How come it is possible?

```
          class Ingredient {
    public:
      string Name;
      int Price;
      string Description;};

      class Pizza {
          vector<Ingredient> ingredients;
        public:
          string Name; 
          void AddIngredient(const Ingredient& ingredient){ingredients.push_back(ingredient);}
      };


    class Pizzeria {
        map<string, Ingredient> mapNameToIngredient;
        map<string, Pizza> mapNameToPizza;
        
        void AddPizza(const string &name, const vector<string> &ingredients)
            {
                if(mapNameToPizza.find(name) != mapNameToPizza.end())
                {
                    throw runtime_error("Pizza already inserted");
                }
                else
                {
                    Pizza pizza;
                    pizza.Name = name;
                    for(size_t i = 0;  i < ingredients.size(); i++)
                     {
                         Ingredient ingredient= FindIngredient(ingredients[i]); //(*)
                         pizza.AddIngredient(ingredient);
                      }
                    mapNameToPizza[name] = pizza;
                }
            }
        
            void AddIngredient(const string &name, const string &description, const int &price)
                {
                    if(mapNameToIngredient.find(name) != mapNameToIngredient.end())
                    {
                       throw runtime_error("Ingredient already inserted");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       Ingredient ingredient;
                       ingredient.Name = name;
                       ingredient.Price = price;
                       ingredient.Description = description;                  
                       mapNameToIngredient[name] = ingredient;
                    }
                }
    const Ingredient &FindIngredient(const string &name) const
    {
        auto it = mapNameToIngredient.find(name);
        if(it != mapNameToIngredient.end())
        {
           return it->second;
        }
        else
        {
           throw runtime_error("Ingredient not found");
        }
    }
    };
class Order {
      vector<Pizza> pizzas; 
    public:
      int numOrder;

      int NumPizzas() const { return pizzas.size(); }
      int ComputeTotal() const;
        {
            int total = 0;
            for(size_t i = 0; i < (size_t)NumPizzas(); i++) //(**) why is it letting me use the method as a static function?
            {
                total += pizzas[i].ComputePrice();
            }
            return total;
        } 
 };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a member function from another member function, the object is implied - it's `this->`.

Comment: I see, thank you. If  inside a non-const method , say `Pizza::AddIngredient`  I do  `Name ="someNAME"` , no problem, WHY? Isn't this a const pointer? It shouldn't allow changes. But If I mark the method as `const`, the following error shows up `candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::__cxx11::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char>'), but method is not marked const` , which is expected but why not in also in the first case? What do they mean with  `'this' argument`  in that error message?

Comment: In a non-`const` member function, `this` is a `const` pointer to a non-`const` `Pizza`. You cannot change what `this` points to, but you can change the contents of the object `*this`.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO you shouldn't be able to call a non-const function from within a const function, you'll get an error like you say.  Whether `this` is const or non-const is determined by the `const` keyword on the function, not by how it's called.

Comment: When you say  "Whether this is const or non-const is determined by..." you meant the pointed object `*this`? From Nathan Pierson's answer, `this`is alway a const pointer

Comment: @J.C.VegaO yes `this` is const, but the object it points to is not - unless it's a `const` function.

Comment: So is it common jargon to say" this can be const or non const", instead of  to the more correct  way (as I see it) : "*this  can be const or non const"? Like some kind of abuse of  language?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO the pointer itself can be const, and the object pointed to can be const - those are independent properties that mean different things.  That makes it really hard to talk about const pointers, so I try to do it as little as possible.